# How to validate rule compare from database and request input

Tags: laravel

How to compare the request input to the database like 
- `exists:users, id` and compare the request input to users table on the id column.

How can I compare the request input greater than, less than from database for example: 
my `money` column got **5**, and I want to withdraw **6**,
the validation must be less than equal 5; if I input 6, then it will error.

so it will be (my_database_variable >= request_input).

---

**EDIT 1**

I think I'm not using the custom validation cause it work on **max**.

But how to pass the parameter on FormRequest(TransactionRequest) ?

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "action"        => "required|in:kylder,koul",
            "amount"        => "required|numeric|min:100|max".$max_amount, //<---- how to pass this from controller
            "currency"      => "required|in:kylder,koul",
            "receiver_id"   => "required|exists:users,id",
            "message"       => "sometimes|nullable"
        ];
    }
```

and in my controller, I am using this to validate

```
public function transaction(TransactionRequest $request)
{
    $max_variable = 20; // <---- I want to pass this on rule()
    $response = $request->validated();
    ...
}
```

*how do I pass the variable of `$max_amount` into rule()*?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lte:field` in your validation which states the validation must be less than or equal to the given field. The two fields must be of the same type. Strings, numerics, arrays, and files are evaluated using the same conventions as the size rule.

Comment: yeah, but `lte:field` only validate static number instead from database variable, like `lte:money` not `lte:10`.

Comment: You'll need to write a custom rule for this then.

Comment: @StormSpirit, I guess you should go with a custom validation rule...

    php artisan make:rule MoneyLessThanFive

Comment: ahh I see, didn't know there is custom validation rule. thanks a lot

Comment: I think I'm not using the custom validation, I just use the `max:$user->current_money` but the problem is, how to pass the parameter on FormRequest.